# How to search through a nested list with a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In Python 3.6, I have a list like the one below and can't figure out how to properly search through the values. So, if I am given the search string below, I need to search through the values for both title and tags and whichever one has most matches, I would return the id for and if there were many different images (ids) with the same amount of matches, then the one whose title comes first alphabetically would be returned. Also, it is supposed to not be casesensitive. So in the code I have search as my term to search and it should return the first id value, but instead is returning different values.

```
image_info = [
{
    "id" : "34694102243_3370955cf9_z",
    "title" : "Eastern",
    "flickr_user" : "Sean Davis",
    "tags" : ["Los Angeles", "California", "building"]
},
{
    "id" : "37198655640_b64940bd52_z",
    "title" : "Spreetunnel",
    "flickr_user" : "Jens-Olaf Walter",
    "tags" : ["Berlin", "Germany", "tunnel", "ceiling"]
},
{
    "id" : "34944112220_de5c2684e7_z",
    "title" : "View from our rental",
    "flickr_user" : "Doug Finney",
    "tags" : ["Mexico", "ocean", "beach", "palm"]
},
{
    "id" : "36140096743_df8ef41874_z",
    "title" : "Someday",
    "flickr_user" : "Thomas Hawk",
    "tags" : ["Los Angeles", "Hollywood", "California", "Volkswagen", "Beatle", "car"]
}
```

]

```
my_counter = 0
search = "CAT IN BUILding"
search = search.lower().split()
matches = {}

for image in image_info:
    for word in search:
        word = word.lower()
        if word in image["title"].lower().split(" "):
            my_counter += 1
            print(my_counter)
        if word in image["tags"]:
            my_counter +=1
            print(my_counter)
    if my_counter > 0:
        matches[image["id"]] = my_counter
        my_counter = 0
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "return"? You aren't returning anything? What exactly is your expected output, and how does it differ from what you have? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: I ran your code and it gave me the first ID inside the matches dict. However, there is a bug with the tags. You lowercase the words in the search string and not in the tags,  but the tags contain some words that are capitalized. You won't be able to match Los Angeles for example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, I am using the search term "CAT IN BUILding" to search through the values of title and tags in the list/dictionary, and I want the function to return how many matches it found. So for "CAT IN BUILding" it should return 1 and the id of where it found the match at 34694102243_3370955cf9_z . If the search term was "building in mexico beach" it should return 34944112220_de5c2684e7_z since that had 2 matches in the tags.

Comment: @bouma I tried to change the words to lowercase in tags, but it gave me an error saying that: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @Mahi, the tags is a list of string. Two lower case, you would right like `[t.lower() for t in tags]` instead of `tags.lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a variation of code where I have attempted to pre-index the data before doing search. This a very rudimentary implementation of how [CloudSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/) or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) would index and search

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
image_info = [
{
    "id" : "34694102243_3370955cf9_z",
    "title" : "Eastern",
    "flickr_user" : "Sean Davis",
    "tags" : ["Los Angeles", "California", "building"]
},
{
    "id" : "37198655640_b64940bd52_z",
    "title" : "Spreetunnel",
    "flickr_user" : "Jens-Olaf Walter",
    "tags" : ["Berlin", "Germany", "tunnel", "ceiling"]
},
{
    "id" : "34944112220_de5c2684e7_z",
    "title" : "View from our rental",
    "flickr_user" : "Doug Finney",
    "tags" : ["Mexico", "ocean", "beach", "palm"]
},
{
    "id" : "36140096743_df8ef41874_z",
    "title" : "Someday",
    "flickr_user" : "Thomas Hawk",
    "tags" : ["Los Angeles", "Hollywood", "California", "Volkswagen", "Beatle", "car"]
}
]

my_counter = 0
search = "CAT IN BUILding california"
search = set(search.lower().split())
matches = {}

index = {}


# Building a rudimentary search index
for info in image_info:
    bag = info["title"].lower().split(" ")
    tags = [t.lower().split(" ") for t in info["tags"]] # we want to be able to hit "los angeles" as will as "los"  and "angeles"
    tags = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tags))
    for k in (bag + tags):
        if k in index:
            index[k].append(info["id"])
        else:
            index[k] = [info["id"]]

#print(index)

hits = []

for s in search:
    if s in index:
        hits += index[s]
print(Counter(hits).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Comment: If I try to run the code that you provided, I get the error: TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given).

Comment: Thanks @Mahi. I have changed the code to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But, I have a question. Right now it is outputting all the image ids and the amount of hits it had, but how would I get it to print out only the image id for the one with the greatest amount of hits instead of all that had hits?

Comment: You can change last line from `print(Counter(hits))` to `print(Counter(hits).most_common(1))` getting only the first hit. Although you should validate size of list before accessing its elements.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to get it to print only the value of the id at the end after I do print((Counter(hits).most_common(1)), but I keep getting both the value of the counter and the ID. I know that it returns a list of only 1 element, but is there a way to print out only the ID?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new entry in dictionary matches[image["id"]] = my_counter.
If you want to keep only 1 entry in dictionary for that search term and you want image_id and count. I have modified your dict and condition. Hope it helps.

```
my_counter = 0
search_term = "CAT IN BUILding"
search = search_term.lower().split()
matches = {}
matches[search_term] = {}

for image in image_info:
    for word in search:
        word = word.lower()
        if word in image["title"].lower().split(" "):
            my_counter += 1
            print(my_counter)
        if word in image["tags"]:
            my_counter +=1
            print(my_counter)
    if my_counter > 0:
        if not matches[search_term].values() or my_counter > matches[search_term].values()[0]:
            matches[search_term][image["id"]] = my_counter

        my_counter = 0
```

Comment: I tried to run the code that you modified and am now getting the error: TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Comment: Python 3.4 return dict_values() instead of list when doing dict.values(). just put list() around matches[search_term].values().   it should be like list(matches[search_term].values())[0]

Comment: Also use lowercase list for tags as highlighted by one user above.